# Disable root login in yocto build

Tags: yocto

I am new in yocto project and I simply want to disable root login in yocto build image? 
I do not want my final image to ask me for login. Simply I need to flash my yocto image on sdcard and no login prompt shows.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `systemd`, in the file meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-serialgetty/serial-getty@.service change the ExecStart in the service to this :

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a USERNAME -8 -L %I @BAUDRATE@ $TERM
```

change USERNAME to root or other.

Comment: Thanks.. I think this will do the trick. As when the root fs boots, the first thing that will be executed is that line you mentined and i will have like an auto login.

Answer (score 3):

iF YOU ARE USING `SYSTEM V` Add below lines in `build/conf/local.conf` file.

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mingetty "
```

Now the below recipe provide the serial inittab open file and look at the `do_install` function

> poky/meta/recipes-core/sysvinit/sysvinit-inittab_2.88dsf.bb
>
> ```
> ./poky/meta/recipes-core/sysvinit/sysvinit-inittab/inittab
> ```

`#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1`  #comment this line in bb file

`1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin root tty1`  # add this line

Comment: thanks, however I am using systemd , any ideas what can be changed and which receipe to do the same as in system V ?

Comment: poky/meta/recipes-core/sysvinit/sysvinit-inittab_2.88dsf.bb  i have mentioned in my post

Answer (score 1):

When you create your image,  add debug-tweaks to `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES`, this will allow no password to root. and add `mingetty`.

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mingetty "
```

After that, edit `/etc/inittab`, comment out the previous line and use mingetty for autologin;

```
#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin root tty1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am actually using systemd. In my local.conf, I added DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd" and VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd". By doing so, I am able to use systemd and also can find the rc0.d , rc1.d etc folders which correspond to sysvinit as I guess but I don't find the inittab script. I can use systemd to accomplish autologin. However, your answer means I must login first in the generated image and modify whether to use systemd or sysvinit files using console, which I am not looking for. I need to autologin in the first boot up of my image. Thanks

Comment: To solve this issue, you can use `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` to execute any commands required such as the ones listed above by Charles C. to modify the rootfs before the Yocto generated image is outputted.  This will overcome the issue of requiring you to login first to execute the commands.