# How to configure yocto so that no one should be able to login as root in yocto image

Tags: linux, permissions, yocto

I am building a yocto image and I do not want anyone being able to login as root in it. I do not wish to remove the account but here is what I want to accomplish.
I want to disable root account access from terminal as well as ssh or create a password that will never validate.
I want to make all files root owner and set them to 700 permissions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780096/disable-root-login-in-yocto-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines to your image recipe.

`inherit extrausers`

`EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -L -e 1 root; "`

This locks the password and expires the account. Make sure you don't have `debug-tweaks` or `empty-root-password` in your IMAGE_FEATURES.

```
$ man usermod
   ...
   -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
       The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is
       specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

       An empty EXPIRE_DATE argument will disable the expiration of the
       account.

       This option requires a /etc/shadow file. A /etc/shadow entry will
       be created if there were none.
   ...
   -L, --lock
       Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted
       password, effectively disabling the password. You can't use this
       option with -p or -U.

       Note: if you wish to lock the account (not only access with a
       password), you should also set the EXPIRE_DATE to 1.
```

Checked:

- Login with ssh is not possible, even though `PermitRootLogin yes` is set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- `$ su - root` is not possible, even though the login shell in `/etc/passwd` still points to `/bin/bash` instead of `/sbin/nologin`
- Login to ftp server via root is not possible

Not Checked:

- I did not check what happens if we add `systemd.unit=rescue.target` or `systemd.unit=emergency.target` to the kernel commandline.
- ... ?

Comment: Anyone who has enough access to the machine to assert arbitrary control over the kernel command line probably cannot be kept out.  Also, anyone with sufficiently unrestricted `sudo` privileges as a non-root user can do almost anything that root can do.  If `/etc` is writable then that includes unlocking the root account and setting its password.

Comment: FS is encrypted. So its ok